# i can't handle any style or Js file on my theme . what is the problem of this file?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

```
function elzero_add_styles(){

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), false,  'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), false,  'all' );
}

function elzero_add_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js',array(),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js',array(),false,true);
}   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'elzero_add_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'elzero_add_scripts' );
```

Comment: Is this file even (properly) included? Also, did you [debug your wordpress](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=debug+wordpress) already?

Comment: Is this in your `functions.php` file? Another thought - if you are working in a child theme you need to replace `get_template_directory_uri` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` because the `template` version pulls from the parent theme.

Comment: yes this is functions file . and i try to change to get_stylesheet_directory_uri
 but is still have the same problem  .

Comment: ok  . but why the js files didn't handle . is there any problem on this ',get_template_directory_uri()'

Comment: @Foda can you be more specific as to how it doesn't work? The files arent loaded? They 404? The includes don't appear in the header? The entire page is a white screen of death? A PHP warning/error? Please be more specific

Comment: Have you tried setting a version number instead of false?

Comment: there is no any error on page . but when i load the index.php page and view the source code . there is no any css or js files handled . this file load as there is no function file . i try to test index .php to see if my work is  correct or any error file name . and i can't see any icluded file on it .

Comment: put an `echo "<h1>MY TEST</h1>"` in the top, so you can see if your `functions.php` is loading

Comment: @DavidLee yes i see this line . but i don't know why any css or js files can't load

Comment: now put it inside the function `elzero_add_styles`

Comment: @DavidLee I do that . but i can't see nothing .

Comment: ok looks like either the action is not triggering or maybe your <head> is static and there is no `wp_head` being called, try `do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );` after the `add_action` also test other action like `'wp_print_footer_scripts'` or similar, we cant help you much with just that piece of code, you need to properly find the root of the issue debugging.